# Vim is auto indenting when inserting certain characters

Tags: python, vim

When editing python files sometimes vim auto indents (left shifts) when inserting following characters `f`, `i` or `l` and I can't seem to reproduce it predictably.

This is Macvim with python settings built in. The only setting I've done regarding indentation is removing `:` from indentkeys by doing `set indentkeys-=:` and `set indentkeys-=<:>` in ~/.vimrc. I've also removed this explicitly in `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/python.vim`.

Following is output of `:scriptnames`:

```
  1: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
  4: ~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim
  5: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim
  6: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/paste.vim
  7: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
  8: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim
  9: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
 10: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
 11: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
 12: ~/.vim/colors/greens.vim
 13: ~/.vim/plugin/comments.vim
 14: ~/.vim/plugin/Haskell.vim
 15: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 16: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
 17: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
 18: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 19: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 20: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
 21: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 22: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
 23: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 24: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 25: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
 26: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim
 27: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/python.vim
 28: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/python.vim
```

Can someone help me find out why this is occurring and how to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins that could interfere?

Comment: Try launching vim with `vim -u NONE` to disable all your config and see if the problem persists, then you'll know if it's in your config or not.

Comment: What happen when you indent a file with the same word ?

Comment: @AndrewMagee Thanks. But this option is not working on `MacVim`. It still loads all plugins.

Comment: Hmm strange. I've never used MacVim so I'm not sure.. I would have just assumed that would work. Did you use `NONE` in all caps? It's case sensitive.

Comment: @AndrewMagee Yes. I used capital `NONE`. When reading python it shows same output for :scriptnames as one I pasted in the question.